# Unsure about how to ask: How can I acoustically treat my attic?

Tags: discussion

I've been setting up the attic as a small home studio, and while the space isn't perfect, it's much better than the room I was recording in before. However, I'd like to gain some insight into how I can improve the space. However, many of the usual strategies for non-pro spaces - hanging blankets on the walls, lining the space with bookshelves - won't really work here.

This is obviously on-topic here, but it'd be best to avoid a discussion-y forum-like question. What would be a good way for me to ask this question here?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to just ask it and see what happens.

If you give a good idea of the shape and structure of the room with pictures or drawings and a fairly good description of what you are trying to accomplish, you should get some good objective answers.

Also, you can always edit the question if you see the discussion-y type answers showing up.